# IntelliJ IDEA Plugin - cannot import package com.jetbrains.python

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plug-in for ItelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5. I set up an Executor class and a GenericProgramRunner class.

I am trying to import the class `com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonRunConfiguration` to use in the `doExecute` method of the runner, but it cannot seem to find the package `come.jetbrains.python`. Says symbol 'python' cannot be resolved.

This is the code of my runner class.

```
public class CheckerRunner extends GenericProgramRunner {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getRunnerId() {
        return "CheckerRunner";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRun(@NotNull String executorId, @NotNull RunProfile runProfile) {
        boolean result = executorId.equals(CheckerExecutor.EXECUTOR_ID) ;
        result = result && runProfile.getClass().toString().contains("PythonRunConfiguration");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected RunContentDescriptor doExecute(@NotNull RunProfileState state, @NotNull ExecutionEnvironment env) throws ExecutionException {

        RunProfile profile = env.getRunProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            System.out.println(profile.getClass().toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The condition `runProfile.getClass().toString().contains("PythonRunConfiguration")` in the `canRun` method evaluates to true.
 The `doExecute` method prints `class com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonRunConfiguration`
 to the console. Why can't I import the class then?

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation about [Plugin Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html)? You need to add the dependency on a Python plugin.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.